# CommandLine Option in Python for filtering values from Column

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments, bioinformatics

I want to write a function in Python for a tab delimited file I am dealing with,to filter out values from a column, and put that parameter as a command line option while running the script.

So,if the limit is 10,the filter out all the rows with values less than 10.
Also,I want to check if the number entered is numeric or not else display the message "its not numeric".

So,the command line would be:

```
python script.py file --quality [limit]
```

The Python script:

```
import sys
arg = []
    for a in sys.argv:
    arg.append(a) 
        quality = arg[2]
```

To be more specific,the file I am dealing with is a Samfile,and using package 
Pysam,which has mapping quality limits in the 5th column.

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pysam/latest/pysam.pdf

Commandline:

```
  python script.py samfile --quality [limit]
```

I am reading the samfile using this:

```
 samfile = pysam.Samfile(arg[1], "rb" )
 mapqlim = arg[2]
```

I am a Python beginner,but saw one of the modules,argparse. How can I accomplish this using argparse in Python?

Function to check numeric

```
  def is_number(s):
     try:
       val = int(s)
     except ValueError:
       print "That is not an int!"
```

If multiple command line arguments are passed,and checking if numeric.

```
  is_number(args.quality)
  is_number(args.count)
```

I wrote a function to check if numeric,however I want to print in case one of them is not numeric, to print "quality is not an int" or "count is not an int" whichever is not instead of "That is not an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)

If you want to get what the quality is provided on the command line, it's going to be code like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--quality", help="enter some quality limit")
args = parser.parse_args()
print "You gave quality = %s" % str(args.quality)
```

Basically, you add arguments to your "parser".  Then you parse your arguments.  The result is an object with properties that have the values you'd expect.

I saved this as `a.py` then ran this:

```
$ python a.py --quality 10
You gave quality = 10
```

Comment: And how can we check if the argument passed is numeric ?

Comment: Use a pretty standard method to tell whether a python value is numeric:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python

Comment: I din't get how to check a command Line parameter to be numeric.Do I pass --quality in the function def ?

Comment: No, --quality is the name of the command line option.   I don't think this module will let you force the argument to be numeric.  Instead, once you get the value, you should check if it's numeric yourself.  Use the link I provided.

Comment: I was able to write a function to check for numeric,however if multiple command line arguments are passed.In that case I want to print in the function which argument is not numeric?I am not able to print out the argument name.

Comment: argparse.add_argument has another option to specify the type of the argument, for instance: `parser.add_argument('--my_int_arg', help='Some help here', type=int, default=0)`.